# Simplifying $\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> The expression $\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}$, where $0<x<1$, is equal to $x$ or $\sqrt{(1+x^2)}$ or $\frac1{\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$ or $\frac x{\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$? (one of these 4 is correct).

My attempt: $$0<x<1\implies 0<\arctan x<\frac{\pi}{4}\implies\frac{1}{\sqrt2}<\cos(\arctan x)<1$$ and $$0<x\sin(\arctan x)<\frac{x}{\sqrt2}$$$$\implies\frac{1}{\sqrt2}<\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x)<1+\frac{x}{\sqrt2}$$$$\implies\frac{1}{2}<(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2<(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt2})^2$$$$\implies\sqrt\frac{-1}{2}<\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}<\sqrt{(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt2})^2-1}$$$$\implies\sqrt\frac{-1}{2}<\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}<\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}-\sqrt2x}$$ Not sure if I have reached anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\arctan x=y;x=\tan y, -\dfrac\pi2 <y<\dfrac\pi2$

As $\cos y>0,$
$$\cos y=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}};\sin y=\tan y\cdot\cos y=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

$$\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

$\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}=\sqrt{{(\sqrt{1+x^2}})^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ for real $x$

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your function at $x=0$ is $0$. Thus it can only be $x$ or $x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$. As $x\to 1$ it tends to $1$. Hence, it must be $x$.

Comment: What a quick approach! +1.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x>0$ and $$1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha},$$ we obtain: $$\sqrt{(\cos(\arctan x)+x\sin(\arctan x))^2-1}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2-1}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2}=x.$$

Comment: Loved the approach, +1.